How to choose a bag to carry lunch straight of the fridge?
I am interested in an isothermic bag to carry my lunch. What characteristics should I look for when looking for which one to buy?
If I understand correctly regardless of each one, adding ice packs is critical?
Also is there a difference between an insulated bag and an isothermic bag?
Update:
Usage: carry cooked food (chicken, beef, rice, pasta) etc straight out of my fridge to the way to the office. My understanding is that such bags can't keep it in proper temperature for hours but should be able to keep it in a very good temperature at least till I get to somewhere I can put the lunchbox in a fridge.  Also has to be small and easy to carry

I don't think this question is answerable as it stands. We would need to know things like what you intend to carry (I'm assuming food), what sort of temperature it is in, what sort of climate you are in and for how long an exposure (i.e. if for cold food how hot is it in your environment and for how long will it be exposed to that), as well as anything else that might influence the decision. In the end this might well boil down to product recommendations, which are explicitly off-topic here.

@bob1: updated post

I think that isothermal bags use some sort of a gel cold pack that changes state at a specific temperature so they tend to stay in a fixed temperature range for an extended period of time.  Unless the cold packs are part of the bag itself (which would take up more space in the fridge or freezer), they’re mostly just an insulated bag. (They might have pockets for the cold packs, or some way to monitor the temperature for the high end medical ones)

After some confusion in comments and flags, I'd like to remind everybody how our site handles "shopping" questions. We don't allow direct asking of "which brand and model of X should I buy", but we do allow "what should I look for in a good X". From my point of view, this question is on-topic for us, and not closeable.

I’m not sure if there’s any good way to tell how well a soft-sided cooler will hold temperature without actually testing it, so here are some considerations that I’ve used:

How easy it is to clean (both inside and out)?  Some have a rubbery or plastic inside that’s easy to wipe down… some also have this on the outside, while others are more fabric-like. Depending on your situation, a fabric outside might be beneficial, as you can wet it down for some evaporative cooling in dryer areas.
How does it close?  Some have zippers, some are Velcro.  Test opening and closing it a few times, as some zippers will get stuck, or Velcro may not grab all that well.
Does it fit what I plan on carrying?  If you have a specific container, like a bento box, it should fit that, possibly an ice pack if appropriate for your area, etc.
It it excessively large or heavy?  If it’s too big, it’s a pain to carry, so it’s hilly best to be the size of the stuff you’re carrying
How durable does it seem?  There are times when you might accept a more flimsy bag for size & weight but just be prepared to replace it sooner, but I would still look over if there are any stitching issues at the seams and straps.  If it has an inner lining, consider how thick it is, as thinner ones will rip sooner.
How do you carry it?  Some larger ones may have a shoulder strap, smaller ones might have a small carrying strap/handle, or it might assume that you’re going to place it in something else.  Also take a note of where the strap is relative to the closure (I had one that pull the Velcro open if you used it), and if your container will be at the proper orientation when using the carrying strap (so it’s less likely to spill)
Does it fold flat?  If you’re going to be returning with an empty bento or similar, this isn’t a consideration, but if you have bagged sandwiches or similar, you may want to collapse it for the return home.  You may want a non-folding bag if you tend to carry stuff loose in the bag (not in a separate hard sided container) that might get crushed, such as fruit.

And for the ice packs… if you’re in a really hot place, and you want to eat your food cold, or it will be held for the whole day, then yes.  Sometimes you have a food that’s eaten closer to room temperature and is relatively safe (some sandwiches, whole fruit, packaged shelf-stable food), so you may not want one so it warms up slightly by the time you’re going to eat.

Please see update in my post

You actually DON’T want to make it too specific, or they’ll close the question because it won’t apply to other people.  Some people think that overly vague questions are not answerable, but good answers make them more useful in the long run.  In your case, I would probably look into a smaller bag that folds up, but maybe also a silicone bag or similar to put the chicken into if it’s fried(or wrap it it freezer paper, which is resistant to grease).  You might also look into some of the silicone containers that collapse after use for the pasta and similar

But the question is about the temperature of carried cooked food and not how to make sure the food is not spilled

@Jim I made tha assumption that getting the food to the other side intact and in a condition that you actually want to eat is implied.  It’s like if you hire someone to build a house, you kinda assume there’s going to be a roof

I get it. Makes sense. Do you have any suggestions about the food safety?

That’s going to be an issue of temperature retention (which is a function of material (type & thickness), surface area, cold pack, how well the bag seals, thermal mass of the food, etc… but also a function of the cleanliness (if something spills or leaks in there, making sure you can clean it well).
